# Get username foreach email

Tags: php, html, mysql

First my code:

```html
<?php
   
if(isset($betreff) && isset($text)){

 $query= "SELECT email, anrede, vorname, nachname FROM newsletter";
 $result= mysql_query ($query);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $anrede= $row['anrede'];
   $vorname= $row['vorname'];
   $nachname= $row['nachname'];
   $email= $row['email'];
   
   $text = str_replace('[A]', $anrede, $text);
   $text = str_replace('[V]', $vorname, $text);
   $text = str_replace('[N]', $nachname, $text);
   $text = str_replace('[E]', $email, $text);
   $body=$text;
   
   strip_tags($text, '<br><b><img><a>');
   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'From: Commeatus-IO <test@test.de>';
   mail($email, $betreff, $body, $headers);
   echo 'Email wurde gesendet an: ' . $email. '<br>';
 }

?>
```

Now this code should Email to every user in the database with the certain email name surname, if I insert in the text `[V]` (for surname) or `[E]` for Email. but if i do this, it shows in every email the same surname and name. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are overwriting the text containing the `[A][N][V][E]` placeholders, and the subsequent iterations can't find them anymore.

Feed your `$body` variable from $text first, this way you won't overwrite your template.

You had also missing a closing curly brace at the end of your loop.

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($betreff) && isset($text)){

    $query= "SELECT email, anrede, vorname, nachname FROM newsletter";
    $result= mysql_query ($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $anrede= $row['anrede'];
        $vorname= $row['vorname'];
        $nachname= $row['nachname'];
        $email= $row['email'];

        // feed $body with your template ($text)
        $body = $text;
        // use $body as the working copy (replace the placeholders in $body)
        $body = str_replace('[A]', $anrede, $body);
        $body = str_replace('[V]', $vorname, $body);
        $body = str_replace('[N]', $nachname, $body);
        $body = str_replace('[E]', $email, $body);

        // I assume you wanted to strip tags in the e-mail text, not in the template      
        strip_tags($body, '<br><b><img><a>');

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Commeatus-IO <test@test.de>';
        mail($email, $betreff, $body, $headers);
        echo 'Email wurde gesendet an: ' . $email. '<br>';
    }  
}

?>
```

Comment: Ahh thanks it works now :) ! i Thought it would be reversed . :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration [A], [V], [N], [E] are replaced and they does not exist in the text anymore, and thus can't be replaced.

Save the text in a new variable and in each iteration do this as following:

```
<?php

if(isset($betreff) && isset($text)){
    $body_text = $text; //Add this
    $query= "SELECT email, anrede, vorname, nachname FROM newsletter";
    $result= mysql_query ($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $anrede= $row['anrede'];
      $vorname= $row['vorname'];
      $nachname= $row['nachname'];
      $email= $row['email'];

      $body_text = str_replace('[A]', $anrede, $body_text);
      $body_text = str_replace('[V]', $vorname, $body_text);
      $body_text = str_replace('[N]', $nachname, $body_text);
      $body_text = str_replace('[E]', $email, $body_text);

      strip_tags($body_text, '<br><b><img><a>');
      $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'From: Commeatus-IO <test@test.de>';
      mail($email, $betreff, $body_text, $headers);
      echo 'Email wurde gesendet an: ' . $email. '<br>';
    }
}

?>
```